# Weird parameters on glfwGetFrameBufferSize

Tags: java, lwjgl, glfw

Been trying to use glfwGetFrameBufferSize to get the pixel area of my window, however when passing in my window for the first parameter it says the type is invalid and the docs say it requests a type of GLFWwindow, which as far as im aware doesn't exist.

The exact error message is as follows: "The method glfwGetFrameBufferSize(long, int, int) is undefined for the type Window"

Anyone know any solutions?

Comment: You should post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says, the signature of your method is wrong. `glfwGetFrameBufferSize` [wants a signature](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwGetFramebufferSize(long,java.nio.IntBuffer,java.nio.IntBuffer)) `(long, IntBuffer, IntBuffer)`. Maybe you are checking [the C++ documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga0e2637a4161afb283f5300c7f94785c9). Also, it is a static method, so you want to call it directly from the class `GLFW` and not from its instances.

Comment: Fixed it. You were right about me having looked at the C++ documentation, I had my variables set as IntBuffers before but it still wasn't working. Turns out my error was good old capitalization. Spelt it as "glfwGetFrameBufferSize" instead of "glfwGetFramebufferSize" Thanks for your help!